# Getting logs from remote clients via rsyslog

Tags: debian, log-files, syslog, rsyslog

I have freshly installed Debian 6. I am trying to get syslog server for a reason, I used to follow manual for this task. I configured /etc/rsyslog.conf on remote client server to send data via udp port 514.

```
$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imklog

*.* @server-ip:514
```

And I also configured server's rsyslog.conf that would accept them.

```
:source, isequal, "client-host-ip" /var/log/clientlog.log
:source, isequal, "client-host-ip" ~
```

I checked my firewall settings and it does pass udp 514 but for some reason things are still not working. What I am missing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server:

```
module(load="imudp") # needs to be done just once 
input(type="imudp" port="514")
```

Check with netstat -nulp on server.

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html

http://www.rsyslog.com/receiving-messages-from-a-remote-system/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already have these lines aswell.

    $ModLoad imudp
    $UDPServerRun 514

netstat -nulp says port is open

    udp | 0 | 0 0.0.0.0:514 | 0.0.0.0:* | 3082/rsyslogd

Comment: Run a tcpdump on client and server like so: tcpdump -i any port 514 and udp.  Check any firewall in between client and server.  Make sure you understand any NAT that may be involved as well.